# Optimising unrounding using maximum likelihood

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I have a bunch of *rounded* random independent numbers. I want to replace them with unrounded numbers such that the unrounded numbers are 'most likely' to have been generated by some (continuous) distribution, eg, a lognormal distribution. What should be my objective function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give an example to illustrate how you might do this:

Suppose you had the following data, which were actually generated by taking $100$ samples of $e^X$ where $X \sim N(2,0.01)$, and then rounding to the nearest integer

```
value   6  7  8  9 
freq    6 44 42  8
```

Then for a lognormal distribution with underlying parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ and cumulative distribution function $F_{\mu,\sigma^2}$, the likelihood of those parameters from these observations would be proportional to $$\left(F_{\mu,\sigma^2}(6.5)-F_{\mu,\sigma^2}(5.5)\right)^{6} \times \left(F_{\mu,\sigma^2}(7.5)-F_{\mu,\sigma^2}(6.5)\right)^{44} \times  \\ \left(F_{\mu,\sigma^2}(8.5)-F_{\mu,\sigma^2}(7.5)\right)^{42}\times \left(F_{\mu,\sigma^2}(9.5)-F_{\mu,\sigma^2}(8.5)\right)^{8}$$

As far as I can tell, this likelihood is maximised with $\hat\mu \approx 2.01361$ and $\hat\sigma^2 \approx 0.00791$, not too far from the original parameters

The real difficulty comes when you then ask for *"the unrounded numbers are 'most likely' to have been generated"*.  You could look for the values corresponding to highest density in each interval using these maximum likelihood estimates, and the result would be $6$ values of $6.4999\ldots$, and $44$ values of $e^{\hat\mu-\hat\sigma^2} \approx 7.43129$, and $42$ values of $7.5$ and $8$ values of $8.5$.  I think that may not be the kind of thing you were looking for

Comment: It is not the result that I was looking for, but it makes sense. I was _perhaps_ hoping for an answer that puts constraints on the mean (and variance?) _within_ each bin, such that the unrounded numbers within each bin match (as close as possible) the conditional (eg, for 5.5<=X<6.5) distribution for these moments?